# Visual artifacts: Firefox or Ubuntu acting weird

Tags: firefox, visual-artifacts

I was browsing though some websites, all of them legit (eBay and Chegg). Then Firefox started doing this weird visual glitch. It flashed for a little bit then just froze. The next thing that happened was that Ubuntu just logged me out. Is this something to worry about or is it something that can just happen?

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/yyIXx.jpg]

Comment: This is looks like GPU artifacting which is often an early symptom of failing hardware. This could also be a bug or corrupted software. You could reinstall the problematic software. If the problem continues to occur you can file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121)

Comment: Are you using any proprietary drivers for GPU? Can you change the driver and open the website again?

Comment: Well I hope that it is a bug. The gpu is only maybe 3 years old. To anser Archisman Panigrahi's quetion I'm using open source drivers and I can still open the website I was on.